# How do I handle a checkbox array to create a feature filter in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, filter

Sorry for my bad english, i'm from Argentina.

I need to manage an array of checkboxes to make a filter. I'm working in a fictional rental car web (I'm still learning, it's a practice), and I want that when I check one or more checkboxes, it only show the cars with those characteristics. Car characteristics are un a .json file (api call).

This is the array of checkbox I've created to map and display in the layout.

```
    export const features = [
  { name: "Manual Transmission", checked: false },
  { name: "5 seats", checked: false },
  { name: "Convertibles", checked: false },
  { name: "Automatic Transmission", checked: false },
  { name: "7 seats or more", checked: false },
];
```

And this is the component "Filter"

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from "uuid";
import { features } from "../../utils/features";
import "./styles.css";
import { FilterContext } from "../../contexts/FilterContext";
import useInput from "../../hooks/useInput";
import { Carlist } from "../CarList";

export const Filter = () => {
  const carsData = useContext(FilterContext);

  const [filteredCars, setFilteredCars] = useState([]);

  const [select, handleSelect] = useInput();

  const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState([]);

  const handleChecked = (e) => {
  };

/*   const featuresList = carsData.map((data) => data.Features2);

  const featuresArray = Object.keys(featuresList).map(function (key) {
    return featuresList[key];
  }); */

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterSelect = carsData.filter((car) =>
      car.VehGroup.includes(select)
    );
    setFilteredCars(filterSelect);
  }, [select, carsData, checkedValues]);

  return (
    <div className="search-container">
      <div className="filter-container">
        <div className="filter-select-container">
          <h2>Filter by</h2>
          <select
            className="filter-select"
            onChange={handleSelect}
            value={select}
          >
            <option value="">All</option>
            {carsData.map((data) => (
              <option key={uuidv1()} value={data.VehGroup}>
                {data.VehGroup}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="filter-checkbox-container">
          {features.map((carFeature) => {
            return (
              <div key={carFeature.name} className="filter-checkbox">
                <input
                  onChange={handleChecked}
                  name={carFeature.feature}
                  type="checkbox"
                />
                <label htmlFor={carFeature.feature}>{carFeature.name}</label>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Carlist carsData={filteredCars} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

CardList:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from "uuid";
import { CardCard } from "../CarCard";

export const Carlist = ({ carsData }) => {
  return (
    <div className="carList-container">
      {carsData.map((data) => (
        <CardCard
          airConditionInd={data.AirConditionInd}
          code={data.Code}
          features2={data.Features2}
          name={data.Name}
          pictureURL={data.PictureURL}
          rates={data.Rates}
          vehGroup={data.VehGroup}
          key={uuidv1()}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

.JSON
https://api.npoint.io/3c713cdde915d38fd6aa

Answer (score 0):

On your `handledChecked` function you should make it add the checked element to your filteredCars state by pushing the new value to this state.

```
setFilteredCars(oldArray => [...oldArray, newElement]);
```

newElement could be an object since your main array is array of objects.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I make the filter? This is my real querry. I have a list of " "car features" in .json and I have to match them with the checkboxes (like a shopping web with filters).